# How to pass arguments and options of a function when using Map?

Tags: labeling, map, style, arguments

Suppose I have a list in which I need to map a function to a list. Also suppose that function takes several arguments and even more options (such as styling). How would I pass all arguments and options when mapping `f` to the list using `Map[...]`?

Below is a simple contrived example...

```
list=Range[10]
fn[arg1,arg2,arg3]:=Module[do something with all args, options->spec]
Map[fn,list] (* how would I pass all arguments and specify style options? *)
```

What if the function I wish to map is a native function (built-in) `NativeFn[...]` with style options? How would I pass those through the `Map[NativeFn,list]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

funcs = {(1 - x)/2, -2 - 3 x};

pt = {x, funcs[[1]]} /. Solve[
    Equal @@ funcs, x, Reals][[1]]

(* {-1, 1} *)
```

Adding options to the [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html)

```
Plot[Evaluate[Callout[#, #, {Scaled[0.8], Above},
     Background -> LightGray] & /@ funcs], {x, -2, 1},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Tooltip[Point[pt], pt]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** When asking a question provide a specific example; otherwise we are guessing what will meet your needs.

```
graphicsPoint[loc_ : {0, 0}, color_ : Red, size_ : 8] := 
  Block[{graphic}, graphic = If[Length[loc] == 2, Graphics, Graphics3D];
   graphic[{color, AbsolutePointSize[size], 
     Tooltip[Point[loc], loc, 
      TooltipStyle -> {22, Black, Background -> LightBlue}]}]];

list = Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], RandomColor[10], 
    RandomInteger[10, 10]}];

Show[graphicsPoint @@@ list, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Which is equivalent to

```
Show[graphicsPoint @@ # & /@ list, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

```
% === %%

True
```

Comment: I really appreciate your attention to this post but it doesn't answer the question. It doesn't address passing extra arguments and options in a `Map` or `MapAt`.

Comment: ???? `/@` **is** [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html).

Comment: oops my bad. The plots are already labeled with `PlotLabels`. The point of my question is to generate a label for the intersection point. That is why I wanted to apply a convenient labeling function to just one (not both) of the equations using `MapAt` at a specific location of interest which is the intersection point. Secondly I really don't want to clutter the `Plot` function too much. That is why I wanted to use MapAt for the equations outside the `Plot` which is why I asked about passing arguments and options when mapping functions onto lists.

Comment: This example shows the pure function `Callout[#, #, {Scaled[0.8], Above}, Background -> LightGray] & ` being mapped onto a list. You can replace that function with whatever you want (assuming that it is compatible with the context, `Plot` in this example).

Comment: Thank you for your help. As you can probably tell I am quite new to Mathematica but have some experience coding (fortran, javascript, php, etc.). I asked question not just to solve how to label points along a plot but also to understand better how  arguments and options are passed using `Map` and variants like `MapAt` and `Apply` outside any enclosing function (i.e. Plot, etc.) so that I could pass these objects around as needed. For example how to pass `f[list, arg2,arg3]:=fn[do something with list and args,options->spec]` when just doing a pure `Map[fn,list]` in global scope?

Comment: I modified the question so it's more general. Would you mind having a third look at this question and see if you can demonstrate it for me just using `Map[fn,list]` in the global scope (not enclosed in another function)?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
list = Range[10]; 
fn[arg1_, arg2_, arg3_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   Return["do something w element " <> ToString[arg1] <> " given " <> 
     StringRiffle[{arg2, arg3}]]]; 
MapAt[fn[#, "a2", "a3"] &, list, RandomInteger[{1, 10}]]
```

[image]

An example with a native functions with different options to explore, [Highlighted](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Highlighted.html).

```
options = {Background -> LightRed, BaseStyle -> {Red, 24}}; 
fn[element_, options_, arg3_] := 
  Module[{}, Return[Highlighted[element, options]]];
MapAt[fn[#, options, {}] &, list, RandomInteger[{1, 10}]]
```

[image]

As Sjörd Smit writes, the options can be a list. Which means you can have a function that creates the options that fit your specific need.

Comment: this was excellent. This solves the case for passing arguments to user-defined and built-in functions. How would I pass style options for built-in functions?

Comment: @JulesManson: Same way, really. The `#` and `&` you see here are short forms of `Function`. It's how you can define functions in-place in Mathematica. I recommend reading the documentation of `Function` for examples.

Comment: @FredrikD so if we had a native function that operates on all members of a list I could do something like this: 

`Map[NativeFunction[#, arg2, Arg3, Frame->True, Background-> LightBlue]&, list]`?

Comment: Yes, no problem. For example, Map[Highlighted[#, Background -> LightRed, 
   BaseStyle -> {Red, 24}] &, list].